# Add WCF reference to JavaScript project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

Any Idea on how to achieve this? I have a WCF service exposing methods to the database and I need to use them from my JavaScript library in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: are you looking for tutorial btw your WCF neeeds to be ajax

Comment: well I have a WCF service..cant I just add a c# library, add the reference there and then use the methods I define in that library in my JavaScript project?